# TableLayoutPanel height for autoscroll based on percentage of visible area

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have an autoscrolling TableLayoutPanel to which I am dynamically adding rows. I would like for the height of each row to be 1/3 of the visible area of the TableLayoutPanel, i.e., the original height of the panel before it gets expanded on the addition of the 4th panel and autoscrolling kicks in. I could just calculate the height for reach row manually and set it as an absolute height, but the TableLayoutPanel could be resized. In that case I could handle the resized event and recalculate the absolute height of each row, but I'm wondering if there is a better way. Is there some way to specify the row height as a percentage of the visible panel area, or should I just go the manual calculation, absolute height route?

Comment: `Answered a similar question` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11051278/763026. Code is there in the github repo (see question / answer comments) to play around with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing what I needed in a top-down FlowLayoutPanel, anchored Top, Down, Left, and Right so that it resizes with the form. The first subpanel is added to the FlowLayoutPanel and assigned a width slightly less than the FLP's width. Every subsequent subpanel is given a Dock style of fill, so that its width automatically matches the first panel. Every panel is assigned a height of FLP.Height / 3 and I have a handler for the FLP's resize event to recalculate the height of the subpanels as necessary.

Thanks to everyone who commented and answered. I'm upvoting your answers since they will be helpful to others, just didn't solve my particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

[TableLayoutPanel.RowStyle.Percent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.rowstyles.aspx)

Row heights are interpreted as percents of the Table's height

If you have a table with 2 rows, each taking 50% of the panel - and wish to add a 3rd, adjusting all to be 33%:

```
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 3;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0].Height = 33F;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].Height = 33F;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 33F));
```

Comment: This works fine for the first 3, but my problem is that when I add a fourth row if AutoSize == true, the TLP expands and there are four evenly sized rows (no scrollbars). If AutoSize == false, the height of the first 3 remains unchanged but the fourth panel is not visible. AutoScroll == true, but no scroll bars appear. I would like for scrollbars to appear and each row to be 1/3 the height of the visible area.

Comment: Also, after experimenting this still does not address the fact that the size is changing when the fourth panel is added. I do not want each row to be 33% of the height anymore, I instead want it to be 33% of the visible height.

Comment: @tronbabylove Put the Table in a host Panel with AutoScroll = true which is the height you want for visible area.  Rows are 1/3rd the height of the panel - and as the TablePanel grows, the Panel handles all scroll bar issues.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually hit on this, but that presented another problem in that I could not get dock the TLP to the container panel without losing the AutoSize functionality, so even if the container panel grew the TLP would stay the same size. I finally tried a FlowLayoutPanel and seem to have implemented what I want. Will post my solution.